# TYPO3 naw_securedl in email

Tags: security, typo3

I have installed **naw_securedl** and it works correctly. But I also need to send the links to the files via emails.
I have stored emails as a pages in backend and when I show the page the links are correctly translated by **naw_securedl**. But if I send an email the links are in normal way.

Is there a possibility to translated also in the email?

TYPO3 version 4.7
naw_securedl version 1.7.1

Comment: How do you send the mails? Which extension do you use for that?

Comment: No extension. Just use mail function. But I can use some extension if you recommend some.

Comment: I don't really understand how you actually send the mails then. You have pages in the TYPO3 backend. But from where is the mail function called? There is an extension called `direct_mail` which is designed to send TYPO3 pages to a list of email receivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nav_securedl`works by hooking into the page rendering process. If you do not render the page like done by the frontend, then you need to call the hook yourself.